# how to use client-go to get the Node status

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I currently have a node here (node *corev1.Node), and I wish to get the node's status to know if it is abnormal, so I do it like that

```golang
for _, statu := range node.Status.Conditions {
  if ! (statu.Type == corev1.NodeReady && statu.Status == corev1.ConditionTrue) {
    return errors.Errorf("Unavailable node")
  }
}
```

I don't know this is right. If it is, is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helpers in https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/c7322e8491689a1f601c606757b87a0cccfd2048/pkg/api/meta/conditions.go#L85

```
IsStatusConditionTrue(node.Status.Conditions, corev1.NodeReady)
```